# Get the src part of a string

Tags: php, image, src

First post ever here, and i really hope you can help.

I use a database where a large piece of html is stored, now i just need the src part of the image tag.

I already found a thread, but i just doesn't do the trick.

My code:

Original string:

```
<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"http://domain.nl/cms/ckeditor/filemanager/userfiles/background.png\" style=\"width: 80px; height: 160px;\" /></p>
```

How i start:

```
$image = strip_tags($row['information'], '<img>');
echo stripslashes($image);
```

This returns:

```
<img alt="" src="http://domain.nl/cms/ckeditor/filemanager/userfiles/background.png" style="width: 80px; height: 160px;" />
```

Next step: extract the src part:

```
preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $image, $matches);

echo $matches ;
```

This last echo returns:

```
Array
```

What is going wrong?

Thanks in advance for your anwser.

Comment: You can use `print_r()` to see the contents of an array for debugging.

Comment: use DOMDocument and DOMXpath

Comment: Do it very dirty - `explode`on `src="`, then explode second value of result on `"`.

Comment: @moonwave99's method works... until you come across `<img src='...' />`

Comment: use `print_r($matches)` instead of `echo $matches` so you will see the structure of `$matches`, because it is an array... not a single variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regexp to solve this kind of problem is [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and will likely lead in unmaintainable and unreliable code. Better us [an HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Using `simplehtmldom` you can easily extract the `src` from the `img` tag:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br/>';
```